# Creating Httpclient Extension with HttpClientHandler

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create my own simple httpclient extension.
What I'm about to ask is, if I'm doing wrong or right. Because I'm still learning and mastering Httpclient. That's why I need your suggestion.

Here's what I've done:

```
     private static HttpClientHandler addHandlers = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        UseProxy = Proxy.UseProxy,
        Proxy = Proxy.UseProxy ? new WebProxy($"{Proxy.ProxyHost}:{Proxy.ProxyPort}") : null,
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; },
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
    };

    private static HttpClient myClient()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient(addHandlers);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
        //  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xml,application/json,text/plain");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd(UserAgent);
        return client;
    }
```

And here's also my question if this is safe of calling myClient?
because if I do, using blocks on myClient, I'm getting an error.

```
 private static async Task<JsonDocument> ResponseMessage(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var client = myClient();

        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {

            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

           ////etc.....
        }
    }
```

if I'm doing wrong, could you please tell me? so that I can correct and I can create a better httpclient extension for long usage for my other projects as well.

Comment: You haven't created any extension, you just set HttpClientHandler's properties. There's no need for a separate function, you're just setting properties for your HttpClient instance

Comment: Oh I see. I thought this is an extension already. Where's the code which I forgot to dispose?

Comment: Putting `ISO-8859-1` as the first charset is really asking for trouble and garbled data. *Everyone* is using UTF8. For ASCII text the same byte values are used by both encodings. For non-Latin encodings though, the characters will get garbled or worse, replaced by `?`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for that information. so, I will only leave the utf-8;q=0.7 alone?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said the opposite about disposing - you should *not* create multiple instances. HttpClient is thread-safe and meant to be reused. You could easily use a `static` instance if your application is short-lived. Using the same instance for long means it won't detect DNS changes, so it must be recycled periodically, eg every 10 minutes. Check [You're using HttpClient wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) for an explanation

Comment: And [You're probably still using HttpClient wrong](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/) about the DNS issue. If you have eg a console application, you can use a static instance. If you have an ASP.NET Core, the easy solution is to use [HttpClientFactory](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2019/09/using-http.aspx) and add HttpClient as a dependency to your controller or action